# Css Error in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have created a button. The Button contains an icon and some text.

The Button has the following features:

- Easy to implement
- If text is longer it switches to two row layout
- Easy to change Color and Sizes and icon position

It costs me a lot of time, but now I finished it.

While doing some testing I find out that the button does not work in IE 11.

I tried a lot changes but nothing helped me.

If you run that snipped in IE there is no text on button 1 and no icon on button two.

If you run it in Chrome, FireFox, Safari and Opera everything works fine.

```css
/* CSS Document */
/*-----------------------Basic Styles---------------------------------*/
/*outer container, contains all parts*/
.btn {
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0;    
    outline-style:none;     
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 38px; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Required for center all the Content, surrounds the Text and the Icon*/
div.btn_innercontainer{
 max-width: 95%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto; /* default value */
}
/*Cointains the Text*/
div.btn_text {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 95%;
    float: left;
    height: 36px;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */ 
    height: 36px; 
}
/*Contains the Icon*/
div.btn_icon {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 6px;
}

/*-------------------------------------Customising options---------------------------------------*/

/*Small Button version*/
.btn_small {
 width: 131px;
}
/*Big Button version*/
.btn_big{
 width:240px;
}
/*Orange Gradient Button*/
.btn_orange {
 border: 1px solid #cd8102;    
    color: black;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #fbd180;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffd800 20%, #ff9d00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(20%,#ffd800), color-stop(100%,#ff9d00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffd800 20%,#ff9d00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffd800 20%,#ff9d00 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffd800 20%,#ff9d00 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffd800 20%,#ff9d00 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffd800', endColorstr='#ff9d00',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background-size: auto 150%;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-position 0.5s; 
}
.btn_orange:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.btn_orange:active {
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
/*Green Gradient Button*/
.btn_green {
 border:1px solid #78b610;
 color: white;
 text-shadow:-1px -1px #3E6101;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #81c510 0%, #577e15 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#81c510), color-stop(100%,#577e15)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #81c510 0%,#577e15 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #81c510 0%,#577e15 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #81c510 0%,#577e15 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #81c510 0%,#577e15 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#81c510', endColorstr='#577e15',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 background-size: auto 150%;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-position 0.5s; 
}
.btn_green:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.btn_green:active {
 border: 1px solid #666666;
}
/*Grey Gradient Button*/
.btn_grey {
 border:1px solid #818181;
 color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #555555;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bfbfbf 0%, #575757 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bfbfbf), color-stop(100%,#575757)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bfbfbf 0%,#575757 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bfbfbf 0%,#575757 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bfbfbf 0%,#575757 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #bfbfbf 0%,#575757 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bfbfbf', endColorstr='#575757',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background-size: auto 150%;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-position 0.5s; 
}
.btn_grey:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.btn_grey:active {
 border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Button Concept</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  
<!--Button with Icon on the LEFT side -->

 <button type="submit" value="&laquo; %%BTBack%%" name="~BT-Addr_Back~" class="btn btn_small btn_green " >
  <div class="btn_innercontainer"> 
     <div class="btn_icon">$</div>
     <div class="btn_text">Preferences</div>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
 </button>

<!--Button with Icon on the Right side -->

 <button type="submit" value="&laquo; %%BTBack%%" name="~BT-Addr_Back~" class="btn btn_big btn_orange " >
  <div class="btn_innercontainer"> 
     <div class="btn_text">Preferences</div>
     <div class="btn_icon">#</div>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
 </button>


 </body>
</html>
```

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that in the Stack Snippet your doctype and head elements aren't working as you may expect, everything you have in your question is *inside the `body` of the snippet iframe*. Not sure if it affects your demo, but considering the symptoms it *may* have influence.

Comment: Yes but same result. Works in every browser except IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your approach is wrong

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/cfrhe5fw/1/

why you need 4 divs

```
<div class="btn_innercontainer">    
<div class="btn_icon">$</div>
<div class="btn_text">Preferences</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

it can be achieved by one div itself (in this case not all the time)

```
<div class="btn_innercontainer">    
Preferences
</div>
```

USE CSS :before property

```
div.btn_innercontainer{
    max-width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto; /* default value */
}

div.btn_innercontainer:before{
    content:"$"
}
```

i am not sure it will work in ie 11, because i dont have it.

but it will certainely help in good coding

Cheers!

Comment: This solution is not optimal, because if there is more text and a two row layout is needed the icon sticks to the upper row. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ m4xx Check this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/cfrhe5fw/2/,**you are wrong** buddy , you can achieve by adding *position*

Comment: The button its self should do that automaticly. If you no remove some text and the button transforms into one row the simbol is under the row.  http://jsfiddle.net/cfrhe5fw/5/

Comment: check this one! http://jsfiddle.net/cfrhe5fw/7/  i get it what you are saying, but normal scenarios you wil be having fixed text ryt, anyways you found the solution cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at your code. To be honest it is very heavy, a lot of your code is not required and there is a better way to mark it up. I know you have spent a lot of time on this for for a simple fix just replace the div's with span's inside the class .btn_innercontainer and it will work in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/fwpzsdv6/3/

```
<!--Button with Icon on the LEFT side -->
    <button type="submit" value="&laquo; %%BTBack%%" name="~BT-Addr_Back~" class="btn btn_small btn_green " >
        <div class="btn_innercontainer">    
            <span class="btn_icon">$</span>
            <span class="btn_text">Preferences</span>
        </div>
    </button>

<!--Button with Icon on the Right side -->
    <button type="submit" value="&laquo; %%BTBack%%" name="~BT-Addr_Back~" class="btn btn_big btn_orange " >
        <div class="btn_innercontainer">    
            <span class="btn_text">Preferences</span>
            <span class="btn_icon">#</span>
        </div>
    </button>
```